# Linking divs with same counter using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, jquery-selectors

I have a table which gets data from the database using PHP.

The table contains the parent 2 elements, lets say they are:

```
Name    Surname    << table row id = info1

Name    Surname    << table row id = info2
```

Beneath every row, there is another row which is hidden by default. When first name is clicked, this is how i want it to display:

```
Name    Surname    << table row id = info1
DOB     City       << table row id = infoSub1

Name    Surname    << table row id = info2
                   << table row id = infoSub2 NOT DISPLAYED
```

How can I implement this in the most effective way?

Thanks

Comment: Do the parent rows have a class, or can you add one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#info1").click(function() {
    $(this).children("#infoSub1").slideDown();
});
```

Then do the same for info2 and infoSub2 :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can give the parent rows a class (for example `parent`), then you can make this very generic with [`.nextUntil()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/):

```
$("tr.parent").click(function() {
  $(this).nextUntil(".parent").toggle();
});
```

This just selects all the `<tr>` elements that *aren't* `.parent` following the clicked row until it finds one that is.   This allows you any number of non-parent rows in-between, and it would toggle them all correctly.  If you have a long table with lots of rows, use [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) in a similar way:

```
$("#tableID").delegate("tr.parent", "click", function() {
  $(this).nextUntil(".parent").toggle();
});
```

This behaves the same, but would attach one event handler to the `<table>` (rather than one per parent `<tr>`).